# Permutations within a scenario outline

Tags: karate

Is it possible for a scenario outline to computate permutations similar to this bash command?

```
$ echo {a,b,c}{d,e,f}
ad ae af bd be bf cd ce cf
```

So something like this would be extrapalated out?

```
Examples:
| cars | tires | size|
|{Honda,Toyota,Kia}|{Big O,Continental,Nitto}|{16|18|20}|

Resulting in
Honda BigO 16
Toyota BigO 16
Kia BigO 16
Honda Continental 16
Toyota Continental 16
Kia Continental 16
Honda Nitto 16
Toyota Nitto 16
Kia Nitto 16
Honda BigO 18
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty simple to write your own function to do this. For example:

```
Feature:

@setup
Scenario:
* def first = ['a', 'b', 'c']
* def second = [1, 2, 3]
* def data = []
* first.forEach(x => second.forEach(y => data.push({ key: x, value: y })))

Scenario Outline:
    * print __row

    Examples:
    | karate.setup().data |
```